# How to determine the smallest number of coins given a number of cents

Tags: java

Assuming there are 5 coin types available: dollars(100 cents), quarters(25 cents), dimes(10 cents), nickels(5 cents) and pennies(1 cent), write a Java program that reads a monetary amount in cents and prints the smallest possible number of coins equaling the amount.  For instance, if 289 is read, your program will print 10 coins: 2 dollars, 3 quarters, 1 dime, and 4 pennies.   Test your program with several different amounts including 100, 99, 1, 141, and 183.  Your output should include the total number of coins as well as the number of each denomination.

```
import java.util.Scanner;
class Hw1 {
  public static void main(String [] args) {
    Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);

    int amounts; //input variables
    int dollars, quarters, dimes, nickels, pennies; //output variables

    System.out.print("Enter an amount in cent:");
    amounts = in.nextInt();

    //steps for computing dollars, quarters, dimes, nickels, and
    //pennies go here

    System.out.println("number of coins = "+ (dollars+quarters+dimes+nickels+pennies));        
  }
}
```

I tried this one time and it was not right.

```
import java.util.Scanner;
class Hw1 {
  public static void main(String [] args) {
     Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);

     int amounts; //input variables
     int dollars, quarters, dimes, nickels, pennies; //output variables
     double totalValue;
     int dollarsValue= 1.00;
     int quartesValue= 0.25;
     int dimesValue= 0.10;
     int nickelsValue= 0.05;
     int penniesValue= 0.01;
     System.out.print("Enter an amount in cent:");
     amounts = in.nextInt();

  //steps for computing dollars, quarters, dimes, nickels, and
  //pennies go here

     System.out.println("number of coins = "+
     (dollars+quarters+dimes+nickels+pennies));

     System.out.print("number of dollars");
     dollars= CONSOLE.netInt();
     System.out.print("number of quarters");
     quarters= CONSOLE.nextInt();
     System.out.print("number of dimes");
     dimes= CONSOLE.nextInt();
     System.out.print("number of nickels");
     nickels= CONSOLE.nextInt();
     System.out.print("number of pennies");
     pennies= CONSOLE.nextInt();

     numberCoins=dollars+quarters+dimes+nickels+pennies;
     totalValue=(dollars+quarters+dimes+nickels+pennies));
      //prinitng out values
       System.out.println("total number of coins" +number of coins);



  }
}
```

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! Instead of posting your homework question without anything you've attempted, please provide your attempts at the solution and explain which part you're having trouble with including any errors you're getting. This will help us give a clear answer for you to help you with your trouble as opposed to doing the whole program for you :)

Comment: Do you know what the algorithm is for getting the smallest number of coins?  Would you know how to do it if you had to do it by hand?  We cannot do your homework for you.  But if you don't know the way to do this and the instructor didn't tell you, I think it's fair enough for us to give you the algorithm, since it's not something everybody could reasonably figure out on their own.

Comment: You do not need anything other than `int` here. `double` and `float` have important implications that make them no good for monetary calculations. (or more specifically, your task here)

Comment: I think the idea is that your program is supposed to figure out the values of `dollars`, `quarters`, etc., not make the user type them in.

Comment: What the heck is `CONSOLE.nextInt`?  (And after that, what is `CONSOLE.netInt`?)

Answer (score 3):

Here's a basic idea of one way you can accomplish this:

1. Begin with the total number of cents you have,
2. Check if you can subtract the largest denomination from that number?

   1. If you can, increment that denomination's counter and subtract it from cents,
   2. otherwise re-test with the next largest denomination.
3. Repeat until `amounts == 0`

I would encourage you to run through this a few times by hand to verify it's validity.

I would also like to point out the significance of three of the test values you were given; 100, 99, and 1. These values are edge cases, and are very common to test in software testing. Related [information here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Edge_case).

---

Amendment based on your edits:

- Do not use `double` or `float` here. Money is typically represented as some fraction of a number by people, but not so by computers. You need no other numeric type other than `int`.
- You are not wanting to ask the user for input (I'm assuming with `CONSOLE.nextInt()` you intended `in.nextInt()`. You want your program to calculate those values.
- Focus on thinking how you can use control statements like `if`, `else if` and `while` into implementing a solution. (Have you learned about these yet?)

Comment: +1 for your elegant explanation :)

Comment: It should be noted that your algorithm (known as a "greedy algorithm") won't work right (produce the minimal number of coins to represent the value) if the coinage includes, say, a 30-cent piece (in addition to the others listed).

Comment: @HotLicks You might be interested in [this](https://cs.uwaterloo.ca/~shallit/Papers/change2.pdf) if you haven't seen it already.  I just found it today.

Comment: @ajb - Mildly amusing.  Of course, the one-cent piece should have been eliminated 20 years ago, but emotional attachment prevents that.  There'd be heck to pay if someone tried to push through an 18-cent piece, no matter how "sensible" it was.

Answer (score -2):

You might want to use an enum, for you need to know which coin has which value

```
enum Coin {
    DOLLAR(100),
    QUARTER(25),
    DIME(10),
    NICKEL(5),
    PENNY(1);

    public final int value;

    Coin(int value) {
        this.value = value;
    }
}
```

Make some additions in the code below, and you're set. Assume you're putting in `289`.

```
static void getMoney(int total) {
    for (Coin coin : Coin.values()) {
        int amount = /* Calculate here how many times the coin value goes into the (remaining) total */
        System.out.println(coin + ": " + amount);
        total = total - /* Calculate here what to subtract from the previous total */;
    }
}
```

Remember: the first coin is `DOLLAR`, so amount should be `2`, and the new total should be `89`. It's up to you to figure out why and how.

Comment: I highly suspect the professor grading this program would go "Hmmmm...." :)

Comment: -1 for doing the guy's homework.

Comment: @HotLicks I sincerely hope the prof would spot this as obviously _not_ from a beginner to Java.

Comment: @HotLicks Is it worth a downvote? I'm exactly telling him *why* I do what I do. I'm giving him an insight in my thought process, so he/she can learn something. Why is that so bad?

Comment: @stealthjong - I've got 25 thousand downvotes I could do.  Yes, it's worth a downvote.