# Coin Math Conversion Issue

Tags: java, eclipse, class, math

i'm currently coding a program that will convert pennies into the correct number of Twenties, tens, fives, dollars, quarters, dimes, nickels, and pennies. I've gotten the first part of the program correct but once i get to dollars my math is not outputting the correct amount. Any help?

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class assignment1 {

public static void main(String[] args) {
    Scanner inputReader = new Scanner(System.in);

    int num, remainder;

    System.out.print("Enter a value as a number of pennies: ");
    num = inputReader.nextInt();

    remainder = num % 2000;

    System.out.println(num + " pennies is equal to:");
    System.out.println((num / 2000) + " twenties");
    System.out.println((remainder / 1000) + " tens");
    System.out.println(((remainder % 1000) / 500) + " fives");
    System.out.println((((remainder % 1000) % 500) / 100) + " dollars");
    System.out.println(((((remainder % 1000) % 500) % 100) / 25) + " quarters");
    System.out.println(((((remainder % 1000) % 500) % 100) % 25) / 10 + " dimes");
    System.out.println((((((remainder % 1000) % 500) % 100) % 25) % 10) / 5 + " nickels");
    System.out.println(((((((remainder % 1000) % 500) % 100) % 25) % 10) % 5) / 1 + " pennies");

}
}
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25437580/how-to-determine-the-smallest-number-of-coins-given-a-number-of-cents/25437710#25437710

Comment: That page doesn't exactly help because i know how to code the individual parts but i'm wonder what's wrong with my math logic in this particular set up. Thanks though for commenting!

Comment: What's wrong with your logic is you're trying to use mathematical operators to do the job of control structures - clarifying question: does your assignment require you to use only math operators to do this?

Comment: It does. Like i said, i understand fully that i could easily build a method, control structure, or function but my assignment does require me to use just the math operators. I appreciate the help!

Comment: Try using the number of pennies as being : 5869
and i SHOULD be getting-
2 twenties
1 tens
1 fives
3 dollars
2 quarters
1 dimes
1 nickels
4 pennies

and the program works all the way up until it gets to the dollars and then messes up :/

Comment: @user3681591: For this question to be useful to future visitors, it might make sense to revert your last edit.  At the moment, the question is confusing, since the problem described isn't exhibited by the code.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ok. I see what you've done. Let's start with

```
System.out.println((num / 2000) + "twenties");
System.out.println((remainder / 1000) + "tens");
System.out.println((remainder / 1000) % 500 + "fives");
System.out.println((((remainder / 1000) % 500) % 100) + "dollars");
```

The first line is correct. But you cannot use a simple remainder to keep a running tally. Also, `num` and `remainder` are terrible variable names. You can do something like this for a running tally,

```
System.out.print("Enter a value as a number of pennies: ");
int pennies = inputReader.nextInt();
System.out.println(pennies + " pennies is equal to:");
int twenties = pennies / 2000;
pennies -= twenties * 2000;
int tens = pennies / 1000;
pennies -= tens * 1000;
int fives = pennies / 500;
pennies -= fives * 500;
int dollars = pennies / 100;
pennies -= dollars * 100;
int quarters = pennies / 25;
pennies -= quarters * 25;
int dimes = pennies / 10;
pennies -= dimes * 10;
int nickels = pennies / 5;
pennies -= nickels * 5;
System.out.printf("%d twenties, %d tens, %d fives, %d dollars, "
        + "%d quarters, %d dimes, %d nickels, %d pennies%n", twenties,
        tens, fives, dollars, quarters, dimes, nickels, pennies);
```

That would output (with 5869 as input),

```
5869 pennies is equal to:
2 twenties, 1 tens, 1 fives, 3 dollars, 2 quarters, 1 dimes, 1 nickels, 4 pennies
```

Or (if you wanted a non-running tally), just remove the subtractions from pennies like

```
System.out.println(pennies + " pennies is equal to:");
int twenties = pennies / 2000;
int tens = pennies / 1000;
int fives = pennies / 500;
int dollars = pennies / 100;
int quarters = pennies / 25;
int dimes = pennies / 10;
int nickels = pennies / 5;
System.out.printf("%d twenties, %d tens, %d fives, %d dollars, "
        + "%d quarters, %d dimes, %d nickels, %d pennies%n", twenties,
        tens, fives, dollars, quarters, dimes, nickels, pennies);
```

And for 5869 you get

```
5869 pennies is equal to:
2 twenties, 5 tens, 11 fives, 58 dollars, 234 quarters, 586 dimes, 1173 nickels, 5869 pennies
```

Comment: Correct! I figured the issue out myself minutes before you posted this- I've revised my source code on this page and thanks man!

Answer (score 2):

This is possible with only mathematical operators. In most other programming task you'll encounter, you should use control structures to accomplish the steps in an algorithm.

**Process**

1. Begin with the number of pennies,
2. Divide by 2000 (the value of a $20-bill) and assign to a new variable,
3. Subtract from the number of pennies the value of the twenties,
4. Repeat for subsequent denominations ($10 bills, $5 bills, etc.)

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem is that each time you divide your number it returns a new number as an Integer. So if you divide 100 pennies by 1000 it returns 0 so the rest of your math is going to return 0 no matter what you do.

example based on your code:

```
//assuming the input is 100 pennies the first remainder/1000 will equal to 0
System.out.println(((((((remainder / 1000) % 500) % 100) % 25) % 10) %5) % 1 + "pennies");
```

You haven't specified that you have to use modulus so i am assuming you're not.
Here's what i would do:

```
System.out.println(num + " pennies is equal to:");
System.out.println((num / 2000) + "twenties");
System.out.println((num / 1000) + "tens");
System.out.println((num / 500) + "fives");
System.out.println((num / 100)  + "dollars");
System.out.println((num / 25)  + "quarters");
System.out.println((num / 10) + "dimes");
System.out.println((num / 5) + "nickels");
System.out.println(num   + "pennies");
```