# How to continue with the value you got in the first variable not start again

Tags: java

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class MoneyChange {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        Scanner reader = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.print("Input an amount of money: ");

        double value = reader.nextDouble();
        int money = (int) value;

        int thousand = money / 1000;
        int fivehundred = money / 500;
        int hundred = money / 100;
        int fifty = (money % 100) / 50;
        int twenty = ((money % 100) % 50) / 20;
        int ten = (((money % 100) % 50) % 20) / 10;
        int five = ((((money % 100) % 50) % 20) % 10) / 5;
        int one = (((((money % 100) % 50) % 20) % 10) % 5) / 1;

        System.out.println("Number of 1000-Bhat Banknote(s) is " + thousand);
        System.out.println("Number of 500-Bhat Banknote(s) is " + fivehundred);
        System.out.println("Number of 100-Bhat Banknote(s) is " + hundred);
        System.out.println("Number of 50-Bhat Banknote(s) is " + fifty);               
        System.out.println("Number of 20-Bhat Banknote(s) is " + twenty);
        System.out.println("Number of 10-Bhat Coin(s) is " + ten);
        System.out.println("Number of 5-Bhat Coin(s) is " + five);
        System.out.println("Number of 1-Bhat Coin(s) is " + one);

        reader.close();
    }
}
```

I would like to know how to continue the values from the first variable onto the other and not start again. Help me out!

Comment: Why would you want to read a double and cast it to int? Also, which variable are you referring to as the first one?

Comment: Maybe [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25539598/coin-math-conversion-issue?rq=1)'ll help

Answer (score 1):

In this code

```
int fifty = (money % 100) / 50;
```

you can calculate `money % 100` and store it in a variable you can re-use it

```
int hun = money % 100;
int fifty = (hun) / 50;
```

Also be aware of [Integer division](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4685450/why-is-the-result-of-1-3-0)

Comment: Thank you so much!

Answer (score 0):

please do small modifications in your program.please take the look below code once.

```
  public static void main(String[] args) {

        Scanner reader = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.print("Input an amount of money: ");

        double value = reader.nextDouble();
        int money = (int) value;

        int thousand = money / 1000;
        int remain =  money % 1000 ;
        int fivehundred = remain / 500;
        remain = remain % 500;
        int hundred = remain / 100;
        remain = remain % 100;
        int fifty = remain / 50;
        remain = remain % 50;
        int twenty = remain / 20;
        remain = remain % 20;
        int ten = remain / 10;
        remain = remain % 10;
        int five = remain / 5;
        remain = remain % 5;
        int one = remain / 1;

        System.out.println("Number of 1000-Bhat Banknote(s) is " + thousand);
        System.out.println("Number of 500-Bhat Banknote(s) is " + fivehundred);
        System.out.println("Number of 100-Bhat Banknote(s) is " + hundred);
        System.out.println("Number of 50-Bhat Banknote(s) is " + fifty);               
        System.out.println("Number of 20-Bhat Banknote(s) is " + twenty);
        System.out.println("Number of 10-Bhat Coin(s) is " + ten);
        System.out.println("Number of 5-Bhat Coin(s) is " + five);
        System.out.println("Number of 1-Bhat Coin(s) is " + one);

        reader.close();

    }
```

Comment: Thank you so much!